# How to mark / tag spring cloud contract generated test

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

is there any possibility to annotate / tag the CDC generated tests?
I would like to group the cdc tests and execute them as separate step in my build pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all present under `target` or `build` and then `/generated-test-sources/contracts`. You can by default exclude those paths and have a separate profile in maven or task in gradle that will include those paths when you want to run contract tests